# Copy Data From One Table To Another AND Adding Additional Data

Tags: mysql

I have a temp table and a regular table in my database.  The column name and types are identical, except the regular table has an extra field.  I am trying to write a query that copies the information from the temp table into the regular table and adds data into the addition field all in one query.

I understand how to copy columns from one table to another (e.g. INSERT INTO TABLE 1 (col 1, etc..) SELECT TABLE2), but how do i do this AND then add in a the value for the new field?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10):

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 (col 1, col2,..., the_extra_col) SELECT *, NULL from TABLE2
```

or

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 (col 1, col2,..., the_extra_col) SELECT *, the_default_date_here from TABLE2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your values

`INSERT INTO TABLE1 (col 1, col2,..., the_extra_col) SELECT *,concat('".$value."') as value1 from TABLE2`

Date means just put `now()` `INSERT INTO TABLE1 (col 1, col2,..., the_extra_col) SELECT *,now() from TABLE2`