# Insert into backup table and add current date

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a question similar to this one:
[Copy Data From One Table To Another AND Adding Additional Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167605/copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-and-adding-additional-data)

I have a production table that sometimes contains non-ascii charaters and we are trying to clean those out while making a backup of all fields so that we can track what was cleaned, when it was created and when it was maintenanced. I have created the backup table by referencing the production table so that both tables are exactly the same.

```
CREATE TABLE acc_nac_bak COMPRESS TABLESPACE sardsm AS
select distinct * from account where acc_id = 1;
delete from acc_nac_bak where acc_id = 1;
```

I later altered the table when I realized it would be good to track the cleaned date:

```
alter table acc_nac_bak add (acc_cleaned_date date default SYSDATE);
```

I then tried this:

```
INSERT INTO acc_nac_bak
VALUES ((SELECT *
FROM account
WHERE regexp_like(acc_address_line_1,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']') OR
regexp_like(acc_address_line_2,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']') OR
regexp_like(acc_address_line_3,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']')OR
regexp_like(acc_address_line_4,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']')OR
regexp_like(acc_address_line_5,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']')OR
regexp_like(acc_name,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']')), SYSDATE);
COMMIT;
```

But when I run that I get an error that there are not enough values.

I need to grab all fields from production table (over 35 fields) into the backup table where there are non-ascii characters, then add the cleaned date.

Is there a way to do this without getting too heavily into FOR loops or IF...THEN? My Google-foo is failing me miserably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can try this

`INSERT INTO acc_nac_bak 
SELECT acc.*,sysdate
FROM account acc
WHERE 
regexp_like(acc_address_line_1,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']') OR
regexp_like(acc_address_line_2,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']') OR
regexp_like(acc_address_line_3,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']')OR
regexp_like(acc_address_line_4,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']')OR
regexp_like(acc_address_line_5,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']')OR
regexp_like(acc_name,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']');
COMMIT;`

Comment: Yes. That works perfectly. Thank you for expanding upon my SQL knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you need?

```
create table acc_nac_bak as 
  select  a.*
        ,sysdate as acc_cleaned_date
  from account a
  where regexp_like(acc_address_line_1,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']') or
  regexp_like(acc_address_line_2,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']') or
  regexp_like(acc_address_line_3,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']')or
  regexp_like(acc_address_line_4,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']')or
  regexp_like(acc_address_line_5,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']')or
  regexp_like(acc_name,'[^ -'||chr(126)||']');
```

(an explicit commit should not be necessary as DDL contains an implicit commit)

Comment: Since this is going to be part of a stored procedure that is run daily, the create table doesn't make sense, but in theory this will work.

Comment: @MKowalski - ah gotcha. One other thing you may find useful is to change your initial create statement to read "CREATE TABLE acc_nac_bak COMPRESS TABLESPACE sardsm as select a.*
        ,sysdate as acc_cleaned_date from account a where rownum < 1; " This statement will coalesce the 3 statements you currently use into a single statement that creates an empty table having the account table structure and appending the acc_cleaned_date column. (using the insert statement above defaulting acc_cleaned_date to sysdate is not necessary)